# Можно ли вызвать оригинальный метод родителя в переопределяющем его методе потомка?

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, переопределение, виртуальная-функция

Есть родитель (закрыт для публичного использования):

```
class BaseElement {
protected:
    unsigned _guid, _size;
    char *_data;
    bool _swap;

    BaseElement(): _guid(0), _size(0), _data(nullptr), _swap(false) {}
public:
    virtual bool Get(char *data, unsigned size);
    //... other stuff
};
```

И потомок:

```
class SimpleBlock : public BaseElement {
    unsigned char _track, _flags;
    short _crpts;
public: 
    SimpleBlock(): _track(0), _flags(0), _crpts(0) { _guid = 0xA3; }
    bool Get(char *data, unsigned size) override;
    //... other stuff
};
```

Метод `Get` у потомка делает то же самое, за исключением того, что сместит указатель `data` на 4 байта вперёд и возьмёт из них значения для своих приватных переменных. Дублировать код `Get` родителя в потомке из-за 4 строчек как-то не красиво.

При указанных выше определениях класса можно ли в реализации `Get` у потомка вызвать тот же метод родителя и просто дописать операции с `_data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо просто указать класс, функцию которого вы хотите вызывать. Например:

```
bool Get(char *data, unsigned size) override
{
    ....
    return BaseElement::Get(data,size);
}
```

Comment: И с виртуальным методом родителя пройдёт?

Comment: Да просто запросто :)

Comment: Блин... Я спросил так как компилятор ошибку выдавал, а она оказалась в другом. )) В любом случае спасибо

Comment: Да без проблем, обращайтесь :)